# Can we stack functions?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript can you do something like this?

```
var b = 1212;
var c = b.toString().length;
```

I am trying to write a program and if I can do this much easier. I need it for a for loop.

```
for(var i = 0; i<=100000 && i.toString().length % 2 == 0; i++){
   //what I need to do
}
```

Comment: Can't you just try it and see?

Comment: Might want to state what it is you wish to accomplish with the program itself. You can chain functions & properties, but the function must return the object itself. In your example, that should work, as `b.toString()` will return a string that has a length property.

Comment: Of what worth is `i.toString().length`? When will it ever be anything but true?

Comment: I can't think of any number that would result in the empty string? What is this condition actually supposed to do?

Comment: Consider that for integers, the length is `Math.ceil(Math.log(n) / Math.LN10)` (this can lead to other properties as well, based on what is *really* desired).

Comment: @user2864740: `ceil()`ed, but yes

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, corrected previous comment.

Comment: @j08691 I have tried it but I got an error.

Comment: @user2864740 I will try Math.ceil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.  It's possible, but not advised inside a for loop like what you are proposing.  A more ideal implementation would be something like...

```
var len = x.toString().length;

for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    //do Something
}
```

...in order to avoid recalculating the value of your would-be 'i.toString().length' for every iteration of the loop.

I'm assuming you didn't actually want to take the length of the string representation of your iterator variable 'i' as it doesn't seem to serve any practical purpose.

Comment: I am sorry. I do actually. I have edited my code above. I actually do need to check the length of the iteration i every time.